# rpy2 error with datetime64[ns] pandas series

Tags: pandas, numpy, rpy2

How can one pass datetime64[ns] data to R from rpy2?  The following simple case:

```py
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjs
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

pandas2ri.activate()

dti = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=3, freq='H')
robjs.r.summary(dti)
```

fails with a ValueError: `ValueError: Unknown numpy array type "datetime64[ns]".` with rpy2 version 3.3.4 and pandas 1.0.5.

Comment: have you tried storing the date as string and then convert it back to datetime in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `DatetimeIndex` to `R`as you do:

```
dti = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=3, freq='H')
type(dti)
pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex
```

try to wrap your data into `DataFrame` object:

```
dti = pd.DataFrame({"DatetimeIndex": pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=3, freq='H')})
type(dti)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

The result is:

```
robjs.r.summary(dti)
array(['Min.   :2018-01-01 00:00:00  ', '1st Qu.:2018-01-01 00:30:00  ',
       'Median :2018-01-01 01:00:00  ', 'Mean   :2018-01-01 01:00:00  ',
       '3rd Qu.:2018-01-01 01:30:00  ', 'Max.   :2018-01-01 02:00:00  '],
      dtype='<U29')
```

Comment: It seems this is not a general solution, as it fails with a different function, like `range`: ```robjs.r.range(dti)```.  Which gives the error "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables"