# Inconsistencies with R functions taking `POSIXct` from rpy2

Tags: pandas, rpy2

Earlier I learned that one needs to enclose a `datetime64[ns]` series in a `pandas.DataFrame`, even with a single column to R's `summary` function for the input to be properly taken as `POSIXct`, like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjs
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

pandas2ri.activate()

dti = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=3, freq='H')
dti_df = pd.DataFrame({"DateTimeIndex": dti})
robjs.r.summary(dti_df)
```

Strangely, calling R's `range` from rpy2 will fail with the same set up:

```py
>>> robjs.r.range(dti_df)
R[write to console]: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

> Earlier I learned that one needs to enclose a `datetime64[ns]` series in a `pandas.DataFrame`, even with a single column to R's `summary` function for the input to be properly taken as `POSIXct`, like so:

(...)

A `pandas.Series` should normally be enough (see https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/blob/master/rpy2/tests/robjects/test_pandas_conversions.py#L239). If not the case, this is likely a bug.

(...)

> ```
> >>> robjs.r.range(dti_df)
> ```

```
  R[write to console]: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

While the R function `summary` accepts R data frames as input, I think that `range()` only accepts R vectors (one-dim arrays).

Comment: Yes, it fails with `pandas.Series` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599909/rpy2-error-with-datetime64ns-pandas-series).  I'll report the bug on GitHub.